# Silverstripe page relation in different languages

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I have created a Link DataObject to automatically let users create a reference to a different page in the Frontend. I use two languages in the frontend, German and English. In the popup I create a dropdown to select the pages

```
public function getCMSFields_forPopup()
{
    return new FieldSet(
        new TextField('Titel'),
        new TextField('URL', 'Externer Link'),
        new SimpleTreeDropdownField('PageLinkID', 'Interner Link', 'SiteTree')
    );
}
```

But I only get the German pages in the dropdown. Tried to change the admin language to English but no change. The database seems to only return the German pages...

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: I did some more digging and found out how to do this. You need to call "disable_locale_filter" before you get your SiteTree objects:**

```
Translatable::disable_locale_filter();
```

Then call "enable_locale_filter" once you've retrieved them:

```
Translatable::enable_locale_filter();
```

---

**These are other approaches which I'll leave here as I think they are still useful...**

I believe you may have to do this using Translatable::get_by_locale() - I assume you only want people to be able to select a page to link to within their language??

Perhaps something like this?

```
public function getCMSFields_forPopup()
{
    $member = Member::currentUser();
    if($member && $member->Locale) {

        $pagesByLocale = Translatable::get_by_locale('SiteTree', $member->Locale);
        $pagesByLocale = $pagesByLocale->map('ID', 'Title', '(Select one)', true);

        return new FieldSet(
            new TextField('Title'),
            new TextField('URL', 'Externer Link'),
            new DropdownField('PageLinkID', 'Interner Link', $pagesByLocale);
        );

    } else {

        // Handle non-member

    }

}
```

Edit: see comments below but another option is to use the Translatable::get_current_locale() function to find all pages in the Site Tree for that locale... if the user is viewing an english page then the locale should be set to english etc...

```
public function getCMSFields_forPopup()
{
    $pagesByLocale = Translatable::get_by_locale('SiteTree', Translatable::get_current_locale());
    $pagesByLocale = $pagesByLocale->map('ID', 'Title', '(Select one)', true);

    return new FieldSet(
        new TextField('Title'),
        new TextField('URL', 'Externer Link'),
        new DropdownField('PageLinkID', 'Interner Link', $pagesByLocale);
    );

}
```

You can also get the locale from the current page e.g.

```
$this->Locale; // From within the model
$this->dataRecord->Locale; // from within the controller
Director::get_current_page()->Locale; // If you're outside the context of the page altogether i.e. code inside your DataObject.
```

Comment: Hi, thx first that works for the member language, but I want people to be able to link to any language that is available in the CMS. So the dropdown would contain the SiteTree for the two languages. Or at least let users link to english pages when they edit english pages.

Comment: I just had a thought regarding "Or at least let users link to english pages when they edit english pages" - you've said this is front-end functionality right? ... using a similar approach you could get the locale from the page they are viewing/editing instead of from the member object. See edits to original answer...

Comment: They don't have the same ID. The SiteTree table in the DB lists the english pages with own ID's so what $obj->getTranslation does, I guess, is check for a translation in SiteTree_Translation table.

Comment: Ahh - yes, you're right. Hopefully the above helps a little anyway.

Comment: @spankmaster79 - I just added a new solution for you. This should do _exactly_ what you want :)

Comment: thx I will try it out monday and then see if it fits. Then you'll get the rest of the bounty ;-) thanks a lot